# Payment Gateway in Single html page application

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have single page html application with just index.html.
From this am requesting payment gateway to proceed payment.

Then they sends status of payment to callback url.

How will i accept this url parameters in html?

Answer (score 0):

In your page to call the payment gateway. The payment Gateway will process its request and return to the **redirect_url** i.e your Site URL with some parameters on it. Check those parameters in web page is loaded in javaScript.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var URL = window.localtion.href;
    var getPageCall = URL.split("?"); //getPageCall[1]  will have all parameters
    var allVariable = getPageCall[1].split("&"); //allVariable will have list of all parameters
    for(var i=0;i<allVariable.length;i++){
            var paraVal = allVariable[i].split("=");
        var parameter = paraVal[0];
        var parameterVal = paraVal[1];
    }
}
```

By above code you can get list of parameters returned and verify the parameter and execute the further process via ajax calls